# How to loop a command in CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I have this code

```
CALL C:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p
GO BACK TO PREVIOUS CALL  
PAUSE
```

How can i go back to the previous call infinite amount of times?

Because when i type a wrong password the bach closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:top
C:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p
goto :top
```

Comment: it does the job, only if the given above is correct.